# Setting innerHTML in Angular 8 causes ReferenceError: mXSSAttempts is not defined

Tags: angular

In my Angular 8 template I set the contents of a div to some HTML (that I fetch from another source) using `<div [innerHTML]="note.text">`.

It works fine in my development environment (via ng serve) but after deployment (ng build and then copy dist folder to my webserver) I get the following error.

```
ERROR ReferenceError: mXSSAttempts is not defined
    at main-es2015.c606d978bcc9a311ab51.js:1
    at Ac.sanitize (main-es2015.c606d978bcc9a311ab51.js:1)
    at main-es2015.c606d978bcc9a311ab51.js:1
    at rs (main-es2015.c606d978bcc9a311ab51.js:1)
    at main-es2015.c606d978bcc9a311ab51.js:1
    at main-es2015.c606d978bcc9a311ab51.js:1
    at Is (main-es2015.c606d978bcc9a311ab51.js:1)
    at Qs (main-es2015.c606d978bcc9a311ab51.js:1)
    at Object.updateRenderer (main-es2015.c606d978bcc9a311ab51.js:1)
    at Object.updateRenderer (main-es2015.c606d978bcc9a311ab51.js:1)
```

I'm using the following version of the Angular CLI...

```
Angular CLI: 8.2.2
Node: 10.16.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.2
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.802.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.802.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.802.2
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.802.2
@angular-devkit/core              8.2.2
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.2.2
@ngtools/webpack                  8.2.2
@schematics/angular               8.2.2
@schematics/update                0.802.2
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.38.0
```

It also fails on my build server which is using...

```
Angular CLI: 8.2.2
Node: 10.16.3
OS: linux x64
Angular: 8.2.8
... animations, common, compiler, core, forms, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.802.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.802.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.802.2
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.802.2
@angular-devkit/core              8.2.2
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.2.2
@angular/cli                      8.2.2
@angular/compiler-cli             8.2.2
@angular/language-service         8.2.2
@ngtools/webpack                  8.2.2
@schematics/angular               8.2.2
@schematics/update                0.802.2
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.38.0
```

Comment: just use  safe navigation operator `[innerHTML]="note?.text"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you implement `safe pipe`

https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/angular-safe-pipe-implementation-to-bypass-domsanitizer-stripping-out-content-c1bf0f1cc36b

Then use the pipe behind note text

```
[innerHTML]="note.text | safeHtml"
```

Quick safeHtml Pipe example

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml'
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  transform(value: string): SafeHtml {
    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This answer worked perfectly. Except for the minor typos that I've since corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoide this error  by using  safe navigation operator which is very useful to protect against null and undefined values in property paths

```
<div [innerHTML]="note?.text">
```