# Angular : unable to show static html pages when hosted into server but works fine when run in local

Tags: javascript, html, angular

In my angular project, I have placed few static html files(sampleText.html in this case) in src/assets/html folder. and in one of my component im trying to fetch and show it. Im using below code to do it. It works perfectly fine when im running npm start and im able to see the html part in localhost as desired. but when i build the same and host using aws amplify and it says "Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application."
here is the frontend code:
ts file:

```
fetch(`../../assets/html/sampleText.html`).then(res => res.text()).then(data => {
  this.content =data;
})
```

in html im rendering as: <div [innerHTML]="content">

Comment: I think you want to change the path of the directory from this  '../../assets/html/sampleText.html' to 'assets/html/sampleText.html' because after the building of the project angular automatically create a asset folder on dist and take the page from there .if not work plz tell me

Comment: or you can render the the page using the routerlink by setting the path to here

Comment: 'assets/html/sampleText.html' this didnt help

Comment: for routerlink idea: it wont help my case because im trying to put that html page in between a dynamic code of another page

Comment: can you share your code on stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to handle this

The first way would be to add `html` to the Rewrites and redirects section of your app. Adding this excludes html extensions from forwarding back to the index.html page, like in the case for a single page app.
Solution found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70325768/1956540

Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html#redirects-for-single-page-web-apps-spa

---

The second way, if you don't want to edit the redirects config, is by using `.txt` extensions and not `.html`:

The angular.json should have `src/assets` already to expose images, favicon, etc.

```json
"assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/assets"
],
```

However, if you wanted to serve them from a different location, like `src/static`, you could add the following config:

```json
"assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/assets",
    {
        "glob": "*.txt",
        "input": "src/static/",
        "output": "/static/"
    }
],
```

Docs here: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#assets-configuration

---

I created another folder under assets called `resources`, then renamed the  static `.html` files to `.txt`. This SO post helped me with the http request: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62369322/1956540

```
// imports
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';


async ngOnInit() {
    
    this.requestStaticHtml()
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
            this.content = data;
    });
}

private requestStaticHtml(): Observable<any> {
    
    const opts: any = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Accept': 'text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
        }),
        responseType: 'text'
    };

    // NOTE: the request here is for the html file but with the renamed `.txt` extension.
    var request = this.http.get<string>('/assets/resources/yourHtmlFileName.txt', opts);

    return request.pipe(
        map((data: any) => {
            return data;
        }), catchError(error => {
            // route to somewhere safe
            return throwError(() => new Error(''));
        })
    )
}
```

The safeHtml pipe I used was based on this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58114926/1956540

```html
 <section *ngIf="content" [innerHtml]="content | safeHtml"></section>
```